# Incrementing variables in Java inside a switch statement?

Tags: java, variables, switch-statement, increment

I just had a quick question regarding incrementing a variable in Java.  My problem is 
I need to increment the charges variable by a certain amount for each package depending on how many hours the hours variable goes over its maximum amount.  I can get it to increment by for one hour over, but I can't seem to figure out how to get the other remaining hours over the max hours to factor into the formula.  Any help is appreciated!

```
case switch (ispPackage) {

    case 'A':
        charges=9.95;
        if (hours>10) 
            charges=charges+=2.00;
        break;
    case 'B':
        charges=13.95;
        if(hours>20){
            charges=charges+=1.00;}

        //charges=13.95;
        break;
    case 'C':
        charges=19.95;
        break;
}
```

Comment: To start a `switch` statement, don't use `case switch`, just `switch`.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you want to do. What are the three cases A, B, and C? In exactly what way does the additional charge depend on the amount the hours go over the maximum?

Comment: Are you trying to add a particular number (2.00 or 1.50) per hour that is over the threshold?

Comment: I will let others answer this question, but i suspect that the solution is going to involve [multiplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication).

Comment: Its the same answer i got when I ran it the first time. It just increments charges by 1 incrementation. I need it to increment the charges variable for how many times the hours variable goes over its maximum hours for each package. i.e if package 'a' goes over its 10 hour allocation for each hour after 10 package 'a' is charged 2 dollars for each hour over. Package 'a' has a 10 hours for its max and gets charged $2 dollars for being over its max hours each hour, package 'b' has 20 hours, but it gets charged $1 being over its hours. Package c doesnt rely on hours its a flat rate. Hope that help

Comment: @TravisMiller check my answer, I updated it

Comment: I think that's it! Thank you very much. I apologize for the confusion in my comments. It was hard to describe what I meant, but I very much appreciate the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are misusing the `+=` operator...

The `+=` operator means `let the value of the variable on the left side be the sum of the current value and the value on the right side`.

```
charge +=2.00;
```

is equivalent to

```
charge = charge +2.00;
```

Also, as per OPs comment, this might be the solution for the original problem:

```
    charges=13.95;
    if(hours>20){
        charges+= (hours-20)*1.00;
    }
```

What does this do? If `hours` is greater than 20, it adds the amount of hours over 20 (`hours-20`) multiplied by the hourly charge (`1.00`) to the actual value of `charges`.

Comment: I think that's it! Thank you very much.  I apologize for the confusion in my comments.  It was hard to describe what I meant, but I very much appreciate the help.